# PayPal transition from IPN to REST API

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-ipn

My company uses PayPal Payments Standard.  Currently our checkout process works via the "cart upload" method and IPN to verify payment via PayPal's website.  Should continue to use this method or if we should replace this with the REST API?  From what I understand, the REST API is only to be used when the customer stays on our website for checkout, as opposed to going to the PayPal site and returning to our site after checkout.  If this is true, I assume the cart upload with IPN method is still the best choice for us, since at this time we prefer to have PayPal handle credit card data.  Am I understanding this all correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REST API is just a different way to integrate the payments programatically.  The functionality is very similar and you'll be just fine sticking with what you're doing.  No logical reason to spend the time redeveloping it if what you have is working fine for you.  They won't be killing it or anything like that (at least not any time in the foreseeable future.)

Comment: Thanks Andrew. If we DID decide to keep checkout on our side but use the rest api, I assume instead of sending the cart I can just charge the total amount as indicated in the examples on the paypal dev site.  In that case, do you know if PayPal Payments Standard supports the REST API or do you have to have another product?

Comment: If you want to keep customers on your site you should explore integrating lightbox checkout: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ec-lightbox/ht_ec-lightbox-migrate/

Comment: @Jody, sure, you can just charge the total amount if that's all you want to send but then you won't have any details about exactly what was purchased when you look at the transaction details in PayPal.  That may or may not be of any concern to you.  The REST API sort of ties Standard, Express Checkout, Pro, etc. into one.  It just depends on which method(s) you choose to provide users.

Comment: I am from the distant future of 2021. PayPal hasn't killed IPN yet but they have made credit card payments much more difficult for any checkouts who have not switched to a REST API Checkout.

Answer (score 1):

As i see from a brief view, REST API for Paypal offers webhooks instead of IPN as a way to notify your system about payments and their progress. Each webhook describes which url gets notification request when some type of event takes place.